# When does thread get into uncancellable sleep state

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-sleep

I have this piece of code where it works perfects in normal case. however , sometimes thread get into uncancelable sleep state.

It means from the state of the process, I see this thread getting into this https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep_nocancel.c.html#__nanosleep_nocancel

```
 struct timespec convertticktotimespec(unsigned long numticks)
{
   struct timespec tm;
  /* separate the integer and decimal portions */
   long nanoseconds =
    ((numticks / (float)sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)) - floor(numticks / (float)sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK))) *
    NANOSEC_MULTIPLIER;
  tm.tv_sec  = numticks / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
  tm.tv_nsec = nanoseconds;

return tm;
}

void *thread(void *args)
{
  struct_S *s = (struct_S *)args;

  while(1)
  {
    s->var = 1;

   struct timespec tm = convertticktotimespec(sysClkRateGet() * 13);

    if ( 0 !=nanosleep(&tm, NULL) ) {
      perror(nanosleep);
    }

  }
}
```

stack trace looks like this

```
Thread 19 (Thread 0x7f225a043700 (LWP 16023)):
#0 0x00007f225b8913ed in __accept_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-  
 template.S:84
#1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () 


Thread 18 (Thread 0x7f225a076700 (LWP 15952)):
#0 0x00007f225b89126d in __close_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () 

Thread 14 (Thread 0x7f225a021700 (LWP 16035)):
#0 0x00007f225b8917dd in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 13 (Thread 0x7f225a032700 (LWP 16034)): 
#0 0x00007f225b8917dd in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
 #1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () 

 Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f225bbb3700 (LWP 15950)):
 #0 0x00007f225ab1e3f3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 #1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

 Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f225a010700 (LWP 16036)):
 #0 0x00007f225b8911ad in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
 #1 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

some how this thread getting into uncancelable sleep state on random , although I dont find the clear definition of this anywhere on internet, so I assume thread getting sleep state forever which can not be interrupted .hence this thread goes to inactive state forever.

I have no clue why is this happening having executing or responsible for  fewer lines of code or instructions.

fromcode.woboq , I found that this gets called from mutex lock.
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc nptl/pthread_mutex_timedlock.c.html#416, but the thread is not using any mutex.

the only thing that i suspect here is , structure struct_s is allocated in the shared memory. this variable is also accessed and assigned by other thread from an another process. does the thread get into this state , internally depending on priority of the threads  ?

Comment: You probably need to show more code, like what happens in `convertticktotimespec`. Hazarding a wild guess... Wrap is affecting your calculations and sleep.

Comment: jww , nanosleep works well all the time, If i attach the gdb to the executble , can see the thread executing nanosleep() on top of the stack trace and other function calls followed by. at some point of time , thread stack trace look like this .

Comment: What does the _thread stack trace look like_?

Comment: @Armali ,that is a very good point. my bad I had not put up in my question.

Comment: The shown stack traces don't contain the `__nanosleep_nocancel` you mentioned, but rather `__accept_nocancel` and `__close_nocancel`, which seem related to socket communication, of which there's nothing in the shown source snippet, so your question is inconsistent.

Comment: All the the in-different stacktraces of the threads I have from the core dump is listed there.

Comment: Note that uninterruptable and uncancellable are quite different things. The latter refers to the ability of the thread to be cancelled with `pthread_cancel`.